# issue apache kafka connection with arduino client

Tags: arduino, apache-kafka

I've a problem when I try to connect my Arduino uno, with the `PubSubClient` library, like a client to my Apache Kafka server.

When I try to establish a connection, on the server I have this:

> [2016-09-07 16:30:59,093] WARN Unexpected error from /192.168.1.104; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network
>   .Selector)
>   **org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 270204932 larger than 104857600)**
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:91)
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:154)
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:135)
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:323)
>           at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:283)
>           at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:472)
>           at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:412)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score -2):

It seems there is inter-broker communication, due to which broker got a request
more than the default allowed size of 10MB. Kindly do a fresh re-install of kafka cluster and see if it helps.